# How do you call functions in a list of functions in Lisp?

Tags: lisp, closures, common-lisp

I'm reading Practical Common Lisp, and I'm playing around with closures (chapter 6) in the REPL. I was trying the following code which I think makes a list of closures, but I can't figure out how to call all of them simultaneously at the REPL:

```
(defparameter *fn*
   (let ((count 10))
     (list
      #'(lambda () (incf count))
      #'(lambda () (decf count))
      #'(lambda () count))))
```

I've read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116590/passing-a-list-of-functions-as-an-argument-in-common-lisp) and tried a few and some others, but nothing seems to work. Here's what I've tried --

```
CL-USER> (apply #'funcall *fn*)
; Evaluation aborted on #<CCL::TOO-MANY-ARGUMENTS #x2100B8890D>.
CL-USER> (funcall *fn*)
; Evaluation aborted on #<TYPE-ERROR #x2100B5667D>.
CL-USER> (loop for function in *fn*
      (collect (funcall function)))
; Evaluation aborted on #<CCL::SIMPLE-PROGRAM-ERROR #x2100C21D4D>.
CL-USER> (map #'funcall *fn*)
; Evaluation aborted on #<CCL::TOO-FEW-ARGUMENTS #x2100B7320D>.
```

What I'm looking for is something that will print (11 9 10).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [mapcar](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm) instead of `map`:

```
CL-USER> (mapcar #'funcall *fn*)
(11 10 10)
```

However, you will notice this prints `(11 10 10)` instead of `(11 9 10)`. That is because `count` is shared between the lambdas in `*fn*`, since the `let` scope encloses them all.

If you want `count` to be bound to different variables in each lambda, you will have to build a distinct `let` scope for each lambda.

Answer (score 4):

```
(funcall (first *fn*))

(loop for f in *fn* collect (funcall f))

(map 'list #'funcall *fn*)

(mapcar #'funcall *fn*)
```